# Start upload after choosing a file, using jQuery.

Tags: javascript, jquery

After having chosen a file for upload, I want the file to be uploaded to database without the click of a button. How is this done using jQuery?

I would like to choose a file like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0408T.gif

```
<input type="file" valign="baseline" />
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Assuming you're using a form:

```
// select the file input (using a id would be faster)
$('input[type=file]').change(function() { 
    // select the form and submit
    $('form').submit(); 
});
```

**EDIT:** *To keep this answer up-to-date:*

There is a nice way to upload files via AJAX without hacks described here:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/

Comment: @Mehd: This isn't ajax. when you change file, form will start to send automatically

Comment: @Mehd: Look at genesis' answer for a complete upload solution.

Comment: I did not understand, please explain more

Comment: No, I Purpose is to upload without refresh?

Comment: If I write myself.
Where do I start? A link would tutorial or explain?

Comment: Just a fast google result: http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html

Answer (score 4):

Use jQuery's plugin [uploadify](http://uploadify.com)

It's great plugin which has many options, and auto-upload, too

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
    'cancelImg' : '/uploadify/cancel.png',
    'folder'    : '/uploads',
    'auto'      : true
  });
});
```

Comment: if you want do use the html uploader, it costs 5$ for non-commerical projects and 100$ for commercial projects.

Answer (score 2):

just set the auto to true.. 'auto':true

Comment: Can you add a link where you see this working because I can't find anything like this.