# Upload Image as soon as user browse their Image from folder

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I needed to ask, what is the way when a user selects an image from input type='file' , file start uploaing via ajax, and display the image in a div. User dont need to press a submit button to intiate uploading.

Thanks - 
Vivek Mishra

Comment: The answer is [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774143/start-upload-after-choose-file-by-jquery

Answer (score 1):

A *View Source* of one such site reveals

```
<input type="file" id="fileupload" onchange="uploadfile(this);">
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

this file will help you to do as you want: http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js  on the other form you want instant image upload..  the examples you will found on http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm

Answer (score 0):

You need a flash/silverlight/java based uploader which does it. There are several:
SWFUpload, Plupload, etc. They have pretty good documentation, with examples.

Answer (score 0):

the basic method for an "ajax" upload, without using flash / silverlight is using a hidden iframe. just set the form's target to the name of the iframe.